# Highcharts: Add point to chart, then remove, then add it again... then repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the Highcharts API, and am using a Column Range chart to represent a schedule of events. The vertical axis represents event IDs, the horizontal axis represents the time.

- User should be able to add a single event by clicking the chart.
- Once added, user should be able to click the newly added event to remove it.
- After removal, user should then be able to click the chart again to re-add the new event in another location.

For the most part, this all works fine - [**See JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/faxmdce5/3/)

On the demo, first click the chart to add a red bar. Then click the red bar to remove it. This is exactly as it should work. **The problem is that if you try to add the red bar again after removing it, the categories on the vertical axis increase.**

**How do I add a point, then remove it, then add it again without "regenerating" extra categories on the vertical axis?**

Here's the code (working JS fiddle is linked above). I've tried to simplify it as much as possible in order to focus on the problem at hand.

```
$(function () {

    var flag = false;

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true,
            events: {
                click: function (e) {                                                               
                    if (!flag) {
                        var y = e.yAxis[0].value;
                        this.series[0].addPoint({
                            name: 'New', 
                            low: y, 
                            high: (y + 10), 
                            color: 'red',
                            events: {
                                click: function () {
                                    this.remove();                                          
                                    flag = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        flag = true;                        
                    }                           
                }
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },                        
        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',                       
            data: [
                [-9.7, 9.4],
                [-8.7, 6.5],
                [-3.5, 9.4],
                [-1.4, 19.9],
                [0.0, 22.6],
                [2.9, 29.5],
                [9.2, 30.7],
                [7.3, 26.5],
                [4.4, 18.0],
                [3.2, 8.5]
            ]
        }]

    });
});
```

I've read through the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and tried everything I can think of but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A collaborative effort between the OP and myself ...*

Re-inject the original x-axis categories and series data :

```
events: {
    click: function () {
        this.remove();
        chart.xAxis[0].update({
            categories: xAxisCategories
        });
        chart.series[0].update({
            data: seriesData
        });
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

where :

- `chart = $('#container').highcharts()`
- `xAxisCategories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
- `seriesData = [....]` (the original series data)

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faxmdce5/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't solve it for me. The chart still generates more and more blank "rows" each time a point is removed and re-added. After 10 or so add/remove/add, it starts to look like this: http://i61.tinypic.com/2nbr9jt.png

Comment: Update: I figured it out. Your answer is correct, just needed to go one step further and re-inject the original data as well. Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/faxmdce5/5/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: Mark, you're right, I didn't notice those extra numbered lines creeping in. It seems crazy that you have to go to these lengths. Like you I would have thought that `this.remove()` would be enough. Some kind of `var x = saveState()` ... `restoreState(x)` would be useful.

Comment: Mark, for anyone reading this later, I have updated the answer to reflect your working solution.